# Angular UI Routing Nested views not working

Tags: angular-ui-router

Here is my index page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="js/NestedApp.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="customApp">
    Index Level
    <a ui-sref="FirstPage">FirstPage</a>
    <div ui-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my FirstPage

```
  <h1>Settings Level</h1>
    <hr />
    <a ui-sref="Firstpage.profile">Profile</a>
    <a ui-sref="Firstpage.account">Account</a>
    <div ui-view></div>
```

Here is my route,js

```
var app = angular.module('customApp', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('FirstPage',
        {
            //url:'/',
            url: '/',

            templateUrl: 'FirstPage.html',

        })
        .state('Firstpage.profile', {
            url:'/profile',
            templateUrl: '../profile.html'

        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/FirstPage');
})
```

First Level routing works fine

Here is url for the first level routing
http://localhost:59367/app/customIndex.html#/

When i click Profile link, here is the error i m getting

Error: Could not resolve 'Firstpage.profile' from state 'FirstPage'

Can someone help me with this

Answer (score 1):

if you rename FirstPage to Firstpage then you will not have any problem.

this is because UI-Router consider FirstPage != Firstpage

your new states should be:

```
.state('Firstpage',
        {
            //url:'/',
            url: '/',

            templateUrl: 'FirstPage.html',

        })
        .state('Firstpage.profile', {
            url:'/profile',
            templateUrl: '../profile.html'

        });
```

and your ui-sref in root will change to:

```
<a ui-sref="Firstpage">FirstPage</a>
```

Comment: the only problem is that Firstpage is spelled different

Comment: Thanks ... Just before I figured it out and was about to post the same but I got the answer from you as well. Thanks